# Go to another page after popup, ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, routes

I want to give two option to user by the popup and after selection I go for the same page, but if some diferences.

```
mapsWazePopup = function () {

var importPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: "Selecione uma das opcoes:",
        scope: $scope,
        cssClass: "popup-import",
        buttons: [
        {
            text: '<b>Maps</b>',
            type: 'button  button-positive',
            onTap: function () {
                $location.path("/Home");
            }
        },
        {
            text: '<b>Waze</b>',
            type: 'button  button-positive',
            onTap: function () {
                $location.path("/Home");
            }
        },

        ]
    });
}
```

and the routes.

```
angular.module("routes", [])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'ionicApp'
})

.state('mapa', {
    url: '/mapa',
    templateUrl: 'templates/mapa.html',
    controller: 'mapaCtrl'

});
```

});

But nothing happen :( I created a .js file just for the routes. I want just to go for this page.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate in angular you have to use $state service instead of $location:

```
 $state.go('home');
//or
 $state.go('mapa');
```

The parameter is the state's name instead of the url.

Answer (score 0):

The onTap function returns a *promise*, so you will want to do something like this instead where you return the path of the button pressed:

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.mapsWazePopup = function () {
        var importPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            title: "Selecione uma das opcoes:",
            scope: $scope,
            cssClass: "popup-import",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: '<b>Maps</b>',
                    type: 'button  button-positive',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        //To do nothing on button press -> e.preventDefault();
                        return ('mapa');
                    }
    },
                {
                    text: '<b>Waze</b>',
                    type: 'button  button-positive',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        //To do nothing on button press -> e.preventDefault();
                        return ('Home');
                    }
    },
    ]
        });
        importPopup.then(function (res) {
            //res is your response from the promise,
            //which will be the path depending on which button was pressed
            console.log('Path: ', res);
            $state.go(res)
        });
    };
});
```

However, in your routes file you have no path to `/Home`.

Use `$state` not location, more info on it [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state). You can read more on ionicPopup [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/), and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEdNJm) of ionics nightly with this type of functionality for you to play around with.